# height is incorrect even with layout_constraintHeight_max/min set to 200dp

Tags: android

[Why doesn't Linear Layout maxHeight work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275473/why-doesnt-linear-layout-maxheight-work/52275783)
[maxHeight does not work on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449828/maxheight-does-not-work-on-recyclerview)

Height of section2 becomes 0 as I followed the instructions from above post.

My View Requirement is to have a:

- TopBar followed by
- 3 sections
- Section1 wraps height followed by
- Section2 maxHeight to 200dp or take/fill available height (followed by Section3)
- Section3 height 45dp and aligns to bottom and
- All 3 sections must be visible.
- This entire view should center_parent of rootView of the activity.

---

- Section1 is correct
- Section3 is correct
- But section2 height becomes 0 and is not visible if I don't set the min constraint.
- If I set minHeight constraint for section2, section3 becomes invisible.

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_home_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    tools:context="mose.moseinc.com.Tymeit.Activities.Home.Activity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/aqua_blue"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <mose.moseinc.com.Tymeit.Views.Home.TopBar
            android:id="@+id/top_bar_home_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </mose.moseinc.com.Tymeit.Views.Home.TopBar>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <CustomView1
                android:id="@+id/section1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/green_theme"
                app:tileHeight="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <CustomView2
                android:id="@+id/section2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/section1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </CustomView2>
            <CustomView3
                android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp">
            </CustomView3>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054567/android-why-is-there-no-maxheight-for-a-view/13811461

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="0dp"` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"` dont work together. Layout_height will always take prio and set the height of CustomView2 to 0.

What you need is to set `android:layout_height="parent"`. Then it will try to take all available space it can get on the screen, but not exceed 200dp.

You set CustomView3 to `visibility="gone"` this does not match your requirement of visibility.

Comment: I made it visible in code. I will make the edit my post above. But the posts I linked suggests that they work together. I can not set android:layout_height to "parent".

Comment: Thing is, that they may work in a ConstraintLayout. You are using a RelativeLayout.

Comment: My 3 sections are inside constraintLayout. I also tried setting layout_height of section2 to fill, match. It does not work.